# Pronunciation of Jehovæ

Tags: pronunciation, names, transliteration, hebrew

The Tremellius and Junio's Bible in Is. 60:1-2 renders the Hebrew name of God (יהוה) as *Jehovæ*. how is this word properly pronounced in Latin?

Thanks!

Comment: Since Latin has been spoken for so long, there is no single pronunciation system for Latin that is unanimously agreed to be the "proper" one. For example, English-speaking students taking a Latin course at school in the United States are likely to be taught to follow the "restored" pronunciation system; singers working on a choral piece might be taught to use an "ecclesiastical Latin" pronunciation system; and English-speaking students of law or medicine might use what Wikipedia calls the "traditional English pronunciation of Latin".

Comment: @Asteroides, this is a very appropriate question. I would mean the context of Bible reading. It's interesting to add another detail, the Tremellius/Junio - Beza Bible, in contrast with the Vulgate, was Protestant so much so that was one of the sources of the KJV. That being said, I don't know whether Protestants pronounced the "ecclesiatical Latin" or the Ciceronian latin. Any insights are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to pronounce it like:

- English scientific or legal Latin, it would be pronounced "jah-HOE-vee"
- If you wanted to give it an Ecclesiastical or modern-Roman
  pronunciation, it would be pronounced "yay-Oh-vay", with a silent H.
- If you wanted to pronounce it according to the *Vox Latina* textbook,
  which is popular these days in academic and educational circles, you
  would pronounce it something like "yay-HOE-why" or "yeh-HOE-why".

So as Asteroides pointed out, you have lots of options. I only listed three.